# rocketchat error during migration after upgrade

Tags: rocket.chat

I recently upgraded rocket.chat from 0.62 to 0.65 in CentOS server. While running `node main.js`, I get the following output:

```
Setting default file store to FileSystem
connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm module instead npm/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:56:20
connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read npm/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:86:15
{"line":"160","file":"rocketchat_migrations.js","message":"Migrations: Not migrating, already at version 121","time":{"$date":1528731630704},"level":"info"}
Updating process.env.MAIL_URL
Using GridFS for custom sounds storage
Using GridFS for custom emoji storage
Push: configuring...
Push.Configure { sendTimeout: 60000,
  apn: undefined,
  gcm: 
   { apiKey: 'XXXX',
     projectNumber: 'YYYY' },
  production: true,
  sendInterval: 1000,
  sendBatchSize: 10 }
GCM configured
Push: Send worker started, using interval: 1000
Exception in callback of async function: Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:3000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1501:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)

➔ System ➔ startup
➔ +-------------------------------------------------------------+
➔ |                        SERVER RUNNING                       |
➔ +-------------------------------------------------------------+
➔ |                                                             |
➔ |  Rocket.Chat Version: 0.65.1                                |
➔ |       NodeJS Version: 8.9.3 - x64                           |
➔ |             Platform: linux                                 |
➔ |         Process Port: 3000                                  |
➔ |             Site URL: http://ZZZZ:3000  |
➔ |     ReplicaSet OpLog: Disabled                              |
➔ |          Commit Hash: 8349c36de0                            |
➔ |        Commit Branch: HEAD                                  |
➔ |                                                             |
➔ +-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Although the server is running, I am not able to access it from the browser. What is the possible error?

Answer (score 0):

I listed all processes running node by `ps -ax | grep node` and killing all them all. I reran the `node main.js` and it fixed everything.